# confliction between flex slider & tiny caroussel

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I'm renewing my website and while I was coding it in HTML I got everything right en 100% working.
Now I converted it to .php with header & footer but at my homepage the 2 sliders conflict with eachother. Sometimes the slider workes and other times the caroussel works..
Does anyone have an idea what this could be and to solve this. Like I said, it worked correctly in the first place.
To give you the idea, this is the website: www.vazcreations.nl
Both codes are here:

```
<div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/slider_img_chemi.png" alt="" class="slider-img">
                    <h1>SEO</h1>
                     Search Engine<br>
                     Optimalisation <a href="#">

                    </a></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/slider_img_artist.png" alt="" class="slider-img"/>
                    <h1>Webdesign</h1>
                     Zie onze portfolio<br>
                     en laat u overtuigen <a href="portfolio">
                    <div class="slider-btn-bg">
                         » Zie ons portfolio
                    </div>
                    </a></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/slider_img_browser.png" alt="" class="slider-img"/>
                    <h1>100%</h1>
                     Cross-browser<br>
                     Compatible <a href="#">

                    </a></li>
                    <li>
                    <img src="images/slider/slider_img_dice.png" alt="" class="slider-img"/>
                    <h1>Alles kan</h1>
                     CMS, Logo's, Designs <a href="mogelijkheden">
                    <div class="slider-btn-bg">
                         » Bekijk de mogelijkheden
                    </div>
                    </a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<div id="slider2">
                <a class="buttons prev" href="#"><img src="images/under_container/recent_creations_prev.png" alt="" class="next-prev"/></a>
                <div class="viewport">
                    <ul class="overview">
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_haags.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_mega.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_vaz.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_haags.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_mega.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                        <li><img src="images/creations/recent_vaz.png" alt="" class="work"/></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <a class="buttons next" href="#"><img src="images/under_container/recent_crations_next.png" alt="" class="next-prev"/></a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Post the suspect code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading jQuery.js twice. The second version wipes out the first and any plugins that were registered to the first .

You only need one version, and it must load before any plugins or dependent code.

Also use browser console to look at errros. Page is throwing syntaxhighlighter error since you are making a call to use it but not including the script in page

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm not really far into jQuery so could you explain a little bit more for me what to do? It's not that i'm lazy, i tried alot but can't really see what you mean. thanks